# How do I run two commands in a single line for loop in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Why can't I run two commands within a single line bash loop?

```
$ for i in {1..100} do printf %s "$(date)" ; mysql -uroot -e "SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G" | grep "Seconds_Behind_Master" ; sleep 10 ; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `mysql'
```

But this simple version works:

```
for i in {1..3}; do echo $i ; ls ; done
```

Comment: newlines are free. Help out the next guy who has to maintain your code and throw some into the mix.

Comment: Right, @glennjackman but when you run a one-off monitoring script in the command line, do you create a file each time?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need a `;` after your  brace expansion.  You have it in the simple example, but not in the "broken" one:

```
for i in {1..100}; do printf %s "$(date)" ; mysql -uroot -e "SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G" | grep "Seconds_Behind_Master" ; sleep 10 ; done
                 ^ this one
```